# HTML 5 Video tag controls not working in Safari and Firefox

Tags: html, cross-browser

Trying to get this code to have functioning controls in Safari and Firefox. The controls show up just not responsive. Code works fine in Chrome.

```
<span class="device image fit"><section id="video">
     <video src="images/Compassionate%20Release%20Healthcare%20Network.mp4" width="100%" controls="true">     
     </video>   
</span>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please share your code / HTML.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there, not in the comments.

Comment: What do you see in safari / firefox ? Is the <video> element visible ?

Comment: Yes, I can see the video frame and time just cannot use the controls.

Comment: Try to correct the hierarchic to see if it helps, it's now: `span-section-video-/video-/span` missing the section close tag. Also to eliminate, change `controls="true"` to just `controls`. If it still doesn't work, lets look at the mp4 file itself.

Comment: Download and check with this video first. Probably video file issue. https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4

Answer (score 1):

The code is missing a close tag for the `section` tag. This may throw off the parser in some browsers.

Simply add one or remove the existing opening tag:

```
<span class="device image fit">
  <section id="video">
     <video src="..." width="100%" controls="true">     
     </video>
  </section>  <!-- add this -->
</span>
```

Comment: He wrote he can see the video element, so this is not the problem

Comment: I think you should remove this answer and add it as a comment to the question

Comment: @JamesPage I already commented about it, but I also know some browser triggers when there is missing tags, such as with responsiveness which is the problem OP describes. The problem if so does not call for any more elaborate answer imo

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to use .mp4 format only, which is not supported in all browser.

You need to provide a different movie format and create some fallbacks for mobile devices or other browsers.

Try writing your `<video>` element like this:

```
<video controls>
  <source src="somevideo.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="somevideo.mov" type="video/mov">
  <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video
</video>
```

This will be supported by most desktop and mobile browsers.

- .mov - supported by Safari, iOS Safari.
- .mp4 - supported by Chrome,
  Android Chrome and Android Browser, IE.
- .webm - supported by Firefox, Chrome and IE.

For further reading, check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) article.

Comment: mp4 is also supported in Firefox (Win7+)